# How to create separate layouts for Nexus 5X and Nexus 6P?

Tags: android, layout

Since the launch of Nexus 5X and Nexus 6P, I have noticed my layout designed previously looks relatively small on these new two devices. I tried creating multiple Layout resource folders but nothing seems to be working efficiently. After going through multiple tutorials and blogs, I am still struggling with this issue. Any kind of help or tutorial would be really appreciated.

Comment: What criteria are you using to split your layout files? `swXXXdp`, `wXXXdp`...?

Comment: I tried layout-xxxhdpi and normal layout folder to separate the layouts, but no luck :(

Comment: You mean it works ? if not what do you mean by " working efficiently" !!

Answer (score 0):

Using multiple layouts is the correct way to solve `Layout` problem only. Besides, you also need adding suitable drawable resolutions and dimensions.

[See more](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html):

Comment: As you can read in my question, I tried that. If I create xxxhdpi layout for Nexus 6p and Nexus 5x then it affects Moto G as well which has relatively low dpi than these two devices. I am struggling to find a right layout folder to put nexus 5x and nexus 6p layouts. Any suggestion?

Comment: @Varundroid.. I am facing the issue for Nexus 6P because it has large screen size however, it takes, Layout.Normal...Can you help

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure to  use dp and sp as your scale.
2. Make sure if the correct layout folder is being picked by the mobile phone (see note below)
3. Resolution of image assets must be proportional to the dpi - check the Android icon resolution requirements and scale your image assets accordingly.

*To determine if the app does pick the layout folder you intend the app to pick - you could change the background for different layout folders and determine which one it picks *